# I am gettig FATAL EXCEPTION, from com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes15.dex)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, classnotfoundexception

i have tried all solutions like placing all gms gradles version same and enabling multiDex, minifyEnable but getting same error again and again. please do help me im fedup all of this.

```
09-23 21:49:23.889 996-996/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                           Process: com.example.haroon.maslapk, PID: 996
                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.example.haroon.maslapk-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes15.dex)
                                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6326)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5918)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5857)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1699)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

This is my gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:0.0.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

Comment: Like you say placing same gms version is mandatory. Could you execeute  androidDependencies task and check that no dependecy is using google play services in different version. I suspect that facebook sdk may have gms dependency.

Comment: can you post android build.gradle

Comment: whenever i remove facebook acountkit sdk no error occurs i think its from facebook's sdk but tell me how to get rid of this i need to use account kit

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

}

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in the app `build.gradle` just under all dependencies written.
And remove this:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

> In your build.gradle of android add followings:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.26.0` appears to have dependencies on version 11.0.1 of some Google Play services libraries.  All versions of Firebase and Google Play services libraries in your build must be the same.  These changes should help:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7' //1.0.2 is available
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:0.0.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'  // CHANGED
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'  // CHANGED
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

Comment: as i already mentioned that i used all versions of gms but same error

Comment: thanks i got solution i just added firebase core, firebase analytics gradles and google gms core and analytics